# Apriori Association Rule Mining - Attribute error

Tags: python, associations, attributeerror, apriori

I want to find association rule with apriori on Python. I have a text data (explanations). In my main function, I point out that my word set is a list of list for each row and union list is a list of all words in text document. Then, I have created a Counter matrix for apriori. Then, I converted this matrix into data frame in order to give a label. Then I want to apply apriori function however I take attribute error: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Does my logic correct? Is there anybody who could help me for solving the error.

**Data sample:**

```
explanation:
[ 'ustu yuklenmis bilgilerinize olan problem yemek ederim', 'secenek ve arz fazla kofte ederim yapip yuklenen']


word_set: 
 ['ustu', 'yuklenmis', 'bilgilerinize', 'olan', 'problem', 'yemek', 'ederim'], ['secenek', 've', 'arz', 'fazla', 'kofte', 'ederim', 'yapip', 'yuklenen']

union_list:
 ['ustu', 'yuklenmis', 'bilgilerinize', 'olan', 'problem', 'yemek', 'ederim','secenek', 've', 'arz', 'fazla', 'kofte', 'ederim', 'yapip', 'yuklenen']
```

**Code:**

```
def transformation_matrix(transactions, support=None): 
    word_set, union_list

    matrix = []
    for item in range(0, len(word_set)):
        count = Counter(word_set[item])
        mat = [count[x] for x in union_list]
        matrix.append(mat)
    return matrix


def data_frame(transactions, support=None):

    matrix = transformation_matrix(transactions, support=None)
    frame_matrix = pd.DataFrame(matrix)
    return frame_matrix


def apriori(transactions, support=None):

    frame_matrix = data_frame(transactions, support=None)
    rules = apriori(frame_matrix, 10)
    return rules


if __name__ == '__main__':

    word_set = []
    for item in explanation:

       splitted = item.split()
       myset = list(set(splitted))
       word_set.append(myset)

    union_list = list(itertools.chain(*word_set))


    print transformation_matrix(explanation[1:30], support=None)
    print data_frame(explanation[1:30], support=None)
    print apriori(explanation[1:30], support=None)
```

Comment: Well, a couple of things, where does `explanation` come from and what do you want to do with `item`? Also yes, `list` doesn't have a `split` method, `str` does (string).

Comment: I have added sample of explanation feature. Explanation comes from the row data @Nobilis